# Department of Labor Jobs API Descriptions Not Available

Tags: data-request, api, labor

We are accessing the jobs available through the DoL for publication on our website. However, the Descriptions are not available. See

```
https://api.usa.gov/jobs/search.json?KEY=XXX&PostingStartDate=11/21/2017&PostingEndDate=11/30/2017
```

How do we access the Descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

Description is available on job details page under `url` key. e.g https://www.usajobs.gov/GetJob/ViewDetails/463201900